# Flowchart always shows all nodes collapsed, any way to expand them?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, activitydesigner

We are using a [flowchart activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as base for our workflow. All the activities that I drop on the designer surface of the flowchart are shown in collapsed state. Even if I click on "Expand all" in the top right of the designer.

First I thought it's a problem with my activity designer code, but the same holds true for standard activities like Sequence: They can not be shown in expanded mode when inside a flowchart. They do not show their regular Expand/Collapse icon in the top right, too.

A little sequence inside another sequence is expandable:
[image]

But inside the flowchart, the same sequence is not:
[image]

Is that by design, intentionally, or am I just missing some very basic piece? I would like to expand individual activities (we have a lot with elaborated designers), but at the moment this seems to work only in Sequence-like base activities, not in flowchart.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be so complicated if your Flow chart has a lot of items so they prefer levels which you can see it in the navigation menu when you hit double click  to the Sequence Item 
and also the Same if you have Sequence WF and you added Flow Chart item will be the Same

Comment: Might be the reason, yes. Basically you say that it's by Design and no way to escape, right? Sometimes it would be pretty helpful  to expand all and printout a Big Poster, then post it to the Wall of the Teamroom...